# How to make the table text never break line?

Tags: html, css, html-table

This is kind a newbie question.

In table cell, if the text is long, how do I make the texts shows in one line ? Never break the line.

The TABLE and TD widths are depends how text long automatically calculated.

For example:

```css
table, td {width: auto}
```

```html
<table border=0>
  <tr>
    <td>text text text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text text text text text text text text text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Take [THIS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/), it's dangerous to develop alone!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `white-space` property on `td` to stop the text wrapping like so:

```
td {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just apply `white-space: nowrap;` on the `td` elements:

```html
<table border=0>
<tr>
  <td>text text text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text  text text text text text text text text text</td>
</tr>
</table>

<style>
table, td {width:auto; white-space: nowrap; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this -

```
<style>
table, td {width:auto; white-space: nowrap; overflow-x: scroll; }
</style>
```